# Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase' not found in C:\wamp\www\test\src\TestTask\PhotosBundle\Tests\Controller\ApiControllerTest.php

Tags: symfony, liipfunctionaltestbundle

When I run the command `php ApiControllerTest.php`, it shows me this error:

> Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase' not found in C:\wamp\www\test\src\TestTask\PhotosBundle\Tests\Controller\ApiControllerTest.php on line 12

My composer is as follows:

```
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7",
    "hautelook/alice-bundle": "^1.1",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3",
    "liip/functional-test-bundle": "^1.4",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8",
    "helmich/phpunit-json-assert": "^1.0
```

My file appkernel is as follows;

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
    $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Hautelook\AliceBundle\HautelookAliceBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\LiipFunctionalTestBundle();
```

and my test controller is as follows; I don't see where is the problem; everythings is include here,

```
<?php

namespace TestTask\PhotosBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Helmich\JsonAssert\JsonAssertions;
use Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ApiControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    use JsonAssertions;

    public function testPostInvalidPhoto()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request(
            'POST',
            '/photos',
            array(
                'tags' => array(
                    'ololo',
                    'trololo',
                )
            ),
            array('image' => $this->getFile(__FILE__)),
            array('HTTP_Accept' => 'application/json')
        );
```

when i run it with commands: phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml.dist, or php vendor/bin/phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml.dist it shows me phpunit  is not recognized

Comment: You should try to run the test with the `phpunit` command, as suggested in the official documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html This should work with one of these commands: `phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml.dist`, or `php vendor/bin/phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml.dist`.

Comment: I tried to do that but it shows me phpunit is not recognized

Comment: Can you please add the outputs of the 2 commands I wrote in your question?

Comment: you were right, it's solved, Thank you , i had just a config error

Comment: You can add an answer with the solution, that may help some other visitors.

Comment: Your first answer is the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run the command `php ApiControllerTest.php`

This fails because you have to *boot* PHPUnit instead of executing the test class directly.

You have to run the tests with the `phpunit` command, as suggested in the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html).

This should work with one of these commands (the current directory must be the root of your Symfony project):

```
phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml.dist src/TestTask/PhotosBundle/Tests/Controller/ApiControllerTest.php
# or
php vendor/bin/phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml.dist src/TestTask/PhotosBundle/Tests/Controller/ApiControllerTest.php
```

You can remove the last parameter if you want to launch all the tests instead of this particular file.